# What exactly does the Docker Desktop memory limit apply to?

Tags: docker

The Docker Desktop for Mac docs state

> By default, Docker Desktop is set to use 2 GB runtime memory, allocated from the total available memory on your Mac. To increase the RAM, set this to a higher number. To decrease it, lower the number.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/

I am unclear what this refers to. Is it the memory available to the desktop software, to the docker virtual machine, to a running container, or to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Desktop for Mac runs a hidden Linux VM, and this setting controls the memory allocation for that VM.  So this is the total memory available to all containers combined.  Options like `docker run -m` can still set a per-container memory limit.